# Is there any possibility to add multiple users to multiple groups using the Graph Api library methods or using HTTP requests in C#?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, httprequest, azure-ad-b2c

Just as the title says, I was wondering if I could use some methods from the Microsoft Graph API library to add multiple users to multiple groups (add members for shortly), or if I could make HTTP requests in c# to be able to add multiple users into multiple groups.

From what I've found out until now, On the web interface of Azure portal, you can select multiple users and add them to multiple groups. I've also read that you could do the same using Powershell scripts, and I was wondering if you could do the same using HTTP requests or the API's library methods.

As for a little background: I've managed to add 10k users into a group, and I want to see if it's possible to add these 10k users into two groups or more, in one call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, there is no related API to add multiple users into multiple groups. As you can find in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp), MS Graph API can be only used to add a member into a group.

If you still want to add members to groups, you could try to use C# to execute Powershell command. You could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/windows-powershell-host-quickstart?view=powershell-7).

Answer (score 2):

Three years later it is possible to add multiple users into one group. ([official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-2-add-multiple-members-to-a-group-in-a-single-request))

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(requestAdapter);

var requestBody = new Group
{
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {
            "members@odata.bind" , new List<string>
            {
                "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}",
                "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}",
                "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}",
            }
        },
    },
};
var result = await graphClient.Groups["{group-id}"].PatchAsync(requestBody);
```

unfortuntately you still can't add them to multiple groups.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I completely forgot about this matter XD